# Pandas> Remove strings ending with backslash and remain strings after backslash?

Tags: regex, pandas, dataframe, window

how can I get rid of every letters before last backslash(including backslash) and I just want to remain rest of it. But I don't know how to make code,,

*original data frame(from xlsx file)
BS1\CB\A2C40001444  42.3
BS1\CB\A2C40006231  32.1
BS1\A2C01345300 44.45
BS1\A2C01345300 44.45
BS1\CB\A2C01345300  44.4

*required data frame
A2C40001444 42.3
A2C40006231 32.1
A2C01345300 44.45
A2C01345300 44.45
A2C01345300 44.4

Comment: Are you trying to remove the `BS1\CB\` part using regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reg expr extract does it for you

1. get all text before last backslash
2. get into a match group everything after last backslash

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""text val
BS1\CB\A2C40001444 42.3 
BS1\CB\A2C40006231 32.1 
BS1\A2C01345300 44.45 
BS1\A2C01345300 44.45 
BS1\CB\A2C01345300 44.4"""), sep="\s+")

df["text"] = df["text"].str.extract("^[\w\\\]*\\\\(.*)")

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
        text    val
 A2C40001444  42.30
 A2C40006231  32.10
 A2C01345300  44.45
 A2C01345300  44.45
 A2C01345300  44.40
```

Comment: wow this is my first question and it works perfectly. i really appreciate!!

Comment: Thank you but can you explain how it works? I tried to find its meaning with googling but failed.With regex analyzer, I was not able to find its real meaning. It is completely working but I cannot understand. ^[\w\\\]*\\\\(.*)     --> ^: starts with next, []: char. set, *: all, \\\\ : from this I cannot understand and (.*): every possible char. set..

Comment: reg expressions are a bit of a dark art....  `^[\w\\\]*` this part matches all alphanumeric chars and back slashes.   `\\\\(.*)` this part a) matches very last backslash then the round brackets say capture everything that comes after it.  Hence the part in the round brackets is part that is captured by `extract()`

Comment: thank you.. additionally \\ means just backflash as I know.. and what does \\\\ means what? and does \\\\ mean 'last backslash'?

Comment: that's regular expression hell ;-). a backslash on it's own has meaning,  so it has to be escaped.  within enclosed square brackets it's escaped by triple,  on it's own by quadruple